# How to keep session alive? Android library Ion

Tags: android, session-cookies

I'm developing an android app that uses [**Ion**](https://github.com/koush/ion) library for requesting API data.

Here is how I'm requesting

```
void getData(final OnDbData listener) {
    Ion.with(context)
            .load(BASE_URL + url)
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject jsonObject) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        listener.OnDbDataReceived(jsonObject, false);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("DBDATA-IonDB", e.getMessage() + "");
                        listener.OnDbDataReceived(jsonObject, true);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

I'm successfully login in to my application but when I send request for other data Ion library is opening new connection and API is returning UNAUTHORIZED error. From the server side the session time out is set to 2 hours. One more thing that is confusing me is that when I use my local server (API in my computer) it is working correctly but when I connect to remote server It is being disconnected. **If you know how to handle this please help!**

Comment: Do you store any token after login? I mean how the server should know who you are if not?

Comment: add code for login and data requests

Comment: No I do not keep any token, because when I was working locally Ion was handling this correctly. @MaksimNovikov

Comment: Login code is also the same, only difference is I send body parameters (email, password) @MaksimNovikov

Comment: but how the server know who you are?

Comment: Server creates a session file with session key, and this session key is sent to user (who is using my app). By exchanging this key client is identified. @MaksimNovikov